# MS Outlook CDO/MAPI Blocking Python File Output?

Tags: python, winapi, outlook, mapi

Here is an example of the problem I am running into.  I am using the Python Win32 extensions to access an Outlook mailbox and retrieve messages.

Below is a script that should write "hello world" to a text file.  I need to grab some messages from an Outlook mailbox and I noticed something weird.  After I attach to the mailbox once, I can no longer print anything to a file.  Here is a trimmed down version showing the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from win32com.client import Dispatch

fh = open('foo.txt', 'w')
fh.write('hello ')
fh.close()

session = Dispatch('MAPI.session')
session.Logon('','',0,1,0,0,'exchange.foo.com\nprodreport');
session.Logoff()

fh = open('foo.txt', 'a')
fh.write('world')
fh.close()
```

If I don't attach to the mailbox and comment out the following lines, it obviously works fine:

```
session = Dispatch('MAPI.session')
session.Logon('','',0,1,0,0,'exchange.foo.com\ncorey');
session.Logoff()
```

Why is opening a session to a mailbox in the middle of my script blocking further file output?  any ideas?  (other operations are not blocked, just this file i/o asfaik)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answering my own question.  it looks like your working directory gets changed when you read the email.  If you set it back, your file i/o works fine.

the correct script would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from win32com.client import Dispatch

fh = open('foo.txt', 'w')
fh.write('hello ')
fh.close()

cwd = os.getcwd()

session = Dispatch('MAPI.session')
session.Logon('','',0,1,0,0,'exchange.foo.com\ncorey');
session.Logoff()

os.chdir(cwd)

fh = open('foo.txt', 'a')
fh.write('world')
fh.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the directory change is a known gotcha when using CDO/MAPI. It is "documented" somewhere in MSDN (eg http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269170). You can reproduce it easily in Python like this:

```
import os
import win32com.client

print os.getcwd ()
win32com.client.Dispatch ("MAPI.Session")
print os.getcwd ()
```